# RPI disconnected and won't connect again to network, how can I resolve the issue?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, internet

Both Wifi and Wired connection not working which worked before.

I set up static IP for both wifi and ethernet.

What options do I have to resolve this issue?

Comment: What have you changed? What's in /etc/dhcpcd.conf? How are you setting a static address? What's the address of your router? Why do you need a static address? If you undo your changes do a regular DHCP address work? Did you note the settings for a DHCP address before attempting to set a static address? Does your router allow setting address by interface MAC addresss? Add some details to your question and folks may be able to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest your first option is to read `man dhcpcd.conf`. Note in particular under the `static value` section the following passage from the author of `dhcpcd`:

> For IPv4, you should use the inform ipaddress option instead of setting a static address.

If you're using IPv6 (instead of IPv4) I'll go ahead and apologize now for what I'm about to say:

> I'll hazard a guess that you didn't read the man page before charging forward, perhaps following a blog post from a member of the TCC. Unless you understand how DHCP and networking in general operate, you really shouldn't start changing default settings in `dhcpcd` - which is your **network manager**.

All that said, if you'd like to edit your question to ask how to set up a static IP, you will get an edited answer here that explains how to do that. If you don't want to do that, I'd suggest that you ***leave `dhcpcd.conf` alone***. Restore it to its original configuration, and I think you will find that things will work quite well.